# Full text search on xml datatype

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

I am working on an application, in which I am parsing the resumes by using third party. That third party return me the response in form of xml. I am storing whole xml in single column. 
Every time number of nodes will be different depend upon the resume supplied.

Now my requirement is to perform fulltext or normal search on this xml data type column. I also need to fetch candidates first name, last name, email and some other important information. My question is how I can peform search on such columns where I don't know the node names.

Comment: Please post your sample xml data

Comment: Page 1 xml, there are 16 pages in word doc.:   <ResumeParserData>
  <ResumeFileName><![CDATA[]]></ResumeFileName>
  <ParsingDate><![CDATA[6/4/2012 12:14:46 PM]]></ParsingDate>
  <TitleName><![CDATA[]]></TitleName>
  <FirstName><![CDATA[Susie]]></FirstName>
  <Middlename><![CDATA[]]></Middlename>
  <LastName><![CDATA[Queue]]></LastName>
  <Email><![CDATA[susie@example.com]]></Email>
  <Phone><![CDATA[2135551234,]]></Phone>
  <Mobile><![CDATA[3105552345]]></Mobile>
  <FaxNo><![CDATA[]]></FaxNo>
  <LicenseNo><![CDATA[]]></LicenseNo>
  <PassportNo><![CDATA[]]></PassportNo>

Comment: <VisaStatus />
  <Address><![CDATA[ ]]></Address>
  <City><![CDATA[]]></City>
  <State><![CDATA[]]></State>
  <ZipCode><![CDATA[]]></ZipCode>
  <!--PermanentAddress  will be provided in future release-->
  <PermanentAddress />
  <!--PermanentCity  will be provided in future release-->
  <PermanentCity />
  <!--PermanentState  will be provided in future release-->
  <PermanentState />
  <!--PermanentZipCode  will be provided in future release-->
  <PermanentZipCode />
  <!--CorrespondenceAddress  will be provided in future release-->

Comment: There are more pages too, but due to comment limit I can't add whole content here. Hope from above you got idea. I want to perform fulltext or normal search on this.

Comment: It seems odd to me that if you're getting this from a service whose job it is to parse the resumes that the format wouldn't be standard. Is it just the number of nodes that is the difference between one resume and the next? If so, an XML index might be a good solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

*An xml data type column stores only XML documents and fragments, and only the XML filter is used for the documents. Therefore, a type column is unnecessary. On xml columns, the full-text index indexes the content of the XML elements, but ignores the XML markup. Attribute values are full-text indexed unless they are numeric values. Element tags are used as token boundaries. Well-formed XML or HTML documents and fragments containing multiple languages are supported.
For more information about querying on an xml column, see Full-Text Index on an XML Column.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522491.aspx*

ALSO, you can use this SQL (UDF) function to get the xml node names

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[XMLTable](@x XML)  
RETURNS TABLE 
AS RETURN 
WITH cte AS (  
SELECT 
        1 AS lvl,  
        x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Name,  
        CAST(NULL AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS ParentName, 
        CAST(1 AS INT) AS ParentPosition, 
        CAST(N'Element' AS NVARCHAR(20)) AS NodeType,  
        x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS FullPath,  
        x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)')  
        + N'[' 
        + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS NVARCHAR)  
        + N']' AS XPath,  
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS Position, 
        x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Tree,  
        x.value('text()[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Value,  
        x.query('.') AS this,         
        x.query('*') AS t,  
        CAST(CAST(1 AS VARBINARY(4)) AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS Sort,  
        CAST(1 AS INT) AS ID  
FROM @x.nodes('/*') a(x)  
UNION ALL 
SELECT 
        p.lvl + 1 AS lvl,  
        c.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Name,  
        CAST(p.Name AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS ParentName, 
            CAST(p.Position AS INT) AS ParentPosition, 
        CAST(N'Element' AS NVARCHAR(20)) AS NodeType,  
        CAST(p.FullPath + N'/' + c.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS FullPath,  
        CAST(p.XPath + N'/'+ c.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)')+ N'['+ CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS NVARCHAR)+ N']' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS XPath,  
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)')
        ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS Position, 
        CAST( SPACE(2 * p.lvl - 1) + N'|' + REPLICATE(N'-', 1) + c.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS Tree,  
        CAST( c.value('text()[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) AS Value, c.query('.') AS this,  
        c.query('*') AS t,  
        CAST(p.Sort + CAST( (lvl + 1) * 1024 + (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) * 2) AS VARBINARY(4)) AS VARBINARY(MAX) ) AS Sort,  
        CAST((lvl + 1) * 1024 + (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) * 2) AS INT)  
FROM cte p  
CROSS APPLY p.t.nodes('*') b(c)), cte2 AS (  
                                            SELECT 
                                            lvl AS Depth,  
                                            Name AS NodeName,  
                                            ParentName, 
                                            ParentPosition, 
                                            NodeType,  
                                            FullPath,  
                                            XPath,  
                                            Position, 
                                            Tree AS TreeView,  
                                            Value,  
                                            this AS XMLData,  
                                            Sort, ID  
                                            FROM cte  
UNION ALL 
SELECT 
        p.lvl,  
        x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),  
        p.Name, 
        p.Position, 
        CAST(N'Attribute' AS NVARCHAR(20)),  
        p.FullPath + N'/@' + x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),  
        p.XPath + N'/@' + x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),  
        1, 
        SPACE(2 * p.lvl - 1) + N'|' + REPLICATE('-', 1)  
        + N'@' + x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),  
        x.value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),  
        NULL,  
        p.Sort,  
        p.ID + 1  
FROM cte p  
CROSS APPLY this.nodes('/*/@*') a(x)  
)  
SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Sort, ID) AS ID,  
        ParentName, ParentPosition,Depth, NodeName, Position,   
        NodeType, FullPath, XPath, TreeView, Value, XMLData 
FROM cte2
```